# Multi client chat server in C - Execution Problem

Tags: c, client-server, chat

I am implementing a Multi client chat server, and i am getting the following error. Only hint i get from the error description is that it is a linker error. Can anyone help me resolving this.

```
viper[1052]% gcc -Wall -o server server.c
server.c: In function âMainServerLoopâ:
server.c:45: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of âacceptâ differ in signedness
/tmp/ccQIY5wn.o: In function `MainServerLoop':
server.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `ListCreate'
server.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `ListCreate'
server.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `ListAddInt'
server.c:(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `ListAddString'
server.c:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `ListAddInt'
server.c:(.text+0x4bf): undefined reference to `ListDeleteInt'
server.c:(.text+0x4cc): undefined reference to `ListDeleteString'
server.c:(.text+0x6d0): undefined reference to `ListDestroy'
server.c:(.text+0x6d9): undefined reference to `ListDestroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status


/*List.h */
#ifndef __RUL_LIST_H__
#define __RUL_LIST_H__

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 21

typedef struct TAG_LIST_ITEM {
 union {
  char strval[MAX_STRING_LEN];
  int  intval;
 } values;
 struct TAG_LIST_ITEM *next;
} ListItem;

typedef struct TAG_LIST {
 ListItem *first;
 ListItem *last;
 unsigned int count;
} List;

List *ListCreate();
void ListDestroy(List **list);

void ListAddString(List *, const char *item);
void ListDeleteString(List *, const char *item);

void ListAddInt(List *, int item);
void ListDeleteInt(List *, int item);

#endif
/* List.h */

/*Server.c*/
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

const int SERVER_PORT   = 13000;
const int BUFFER_SIZE  = 256;
const int MAX_BUFFER_NUM = 100;

const int MAX_CLIENT_ID_LEN = MAX_STRING_LEN - 1;

void MainServerLoop(int);
void HandleClient(int connfd);
int  Max(List *list);

void MainServerLoop(int sockfd)
{
 char clientID[MAX_CLIENT_ID_LEN + 1];
 List *listClientID = ListCreate();

 int connfd, i;
 struct sockaddr_in cliAddr;
 int lenAddr = sizeof(cliAddr);

 fd_set readfds;
 FD_ZERO(&readfds);
 List *listSock = ListCreate();
 ListAddInt(listSock, sockfd);
 FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);

 char readbuf[BUFFER_SIZE];
 char writebuf[MAX_BUFFER_NUM][BUFFER_SIZE];
 int numWriteBuf = 0;

 while (select(Max(listSock) + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) >= 0)
 {
  if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds))  // listening socket
  {
   connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliAddr, &lenAddr);
   if (connfd < 0)
   {
    printf("error while calling accept()\n");
    exit(1);
   }

   int len = read(connfd, clientID, MAX_CLIENT_ID_LEN);
   if (len > 0)
   {
    if (clientID[len] != '\0')
    {
     clientID[len] = '\0';
    }

    ListAddString(listClientID, clientID);
    printf("user %s logged in\n", clientID);
    ListAddInt(listSock, connfd);
    printf("Number of user : %d\n", listClientID->count);
    printf("Number of sock desc : %d\n" , listSock->count);

    if (numWriteBuf < MAX_BUFFER_NUM)
    {
     sprintf(writebuf[numWriteBuf++], "User %s logged in\n", clientID);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    close(connfd);
   }
  }

  ListItem *sockItem = listSock->first;
  if (sockItem) sockItem = sockItem->next; // bypass listening socket
  ListItem *clientIDItem = listClientID->first;
  while (sockItem != 0 && clientIDItem != 0)
  {
   if (FD_ISSET(sockItem->values.intval, &readfds)) // connected socket
   {
    int len = read(sockItem->values.intval, readbuf, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
    if (len > 0)
    {
     if (numWriteBuf < MAX_BUFFER_NUM)
     {
      readbuf[len] = '\0';
      strcpy(writebuf[numWriteBuf], clientIDItem->values.strval);
      strncat(writebuf[numWriteBuf], ": ", 2);
      strncat(writebuf[numWriteBuf], readbuf, len);
      ++numWriteBuf;
     }
    }
    else if (len == 0)
    {
     ListItem *nextSock = sockItem->next;
     ListItem *nextClient = clientIDItem->next;

     FD_CLR(sockItem->values.intval, &readfds);
     close(sockItem->values.intval);
     printf("user %s logged off\n", clientIDItem->values.strval);
     ListDeleteInt(listSock, sockItem->values.intval);
     ListDeleteString(listClientID, clientIDItem->values.strval);
     printf("Number of user : %d\n", listClientID->count);
     printf("Number of sock desc : %d\n" , listSock->count);

     if (numWriteBuf < MAX_BUFFER_NUM)
     {
      sprintf(writebuf[numWriteBuf++], 
       "User %s logged off\n", clientIDItem->values.strval);
     }

     sockItem = nextSock;
     clientIDItem = nextClient;
     continue;
    }
   }

   sockItem = sockItem->next;
   clientIDItem = clientIDItem->next;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numWriteBuf; ++i)
  {
   sockItem = listSock->first;
   if (sockItem) sockItem = sockItem->next; // bypass listening socket
   while (sockItem != 0)
   {
    write(sockItem->values.intval, writebuf[i], strlen(writebuf[i]) + 1);
    sockItem = sockItem->next;
   }
  }
  numWriteBuf = 0;

  sockItem = listSock->first;
  while (sockItem != 0)
  {
   FD_SET(sockItem->values.intval, &readfds);
   sockItem = sockItem->next;
  } 
 }

 printf("server error %d, exit !\n",errno);
 ListDestroy(&listSock);
 ListDestroy(&listClientID);
}

int Max(List *listInt)
{
 if (listInt->first == 0) return 0;

 ListItem *curItem = listInt->first;
 int max = curItem->values.intval;
 curItem = curItem->next;

 while (curItem != 0)
 {
  if (curItem->values.intval > max) 
  {
   max = curItem->values.intval;
  }
  curItem = curItem->next;
 }

 return max;
}


int main()
{
 int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0)
 {
  printf("socket() function failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 struct sockaddr_in addr;
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
 addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
 {
  printf("bind() function failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) < 0)
 {
  printf("listen() function failed\n");
  exit(1);
 }

 printf("server started, listening at port %d\n", SERVER_PORT);

 MainServerLoop(sockfd);

 return 0;
}
/* Server.c*/
```

Comment: @unwind - @artelius
I am really sorry i did a very silly mistake of including the list.c while compiling. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the implementation of the list functions, i.e. the file `list.c`, so the compiler sees it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o server server.c list.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Linker errors indicate that some functions or [global] variables referenced by a file are missing. They could either be located in a library or in a source file you forgot to compile and/or link with.